# Multi Filter ORACLE Apex Popup LOV

Tags: oracle-apex

How can I can create Popup Lov item with multi filter ?
I want to create multi filter in popup Lov item , I need:

- three search filter appear;
- one free text search;
- two selected list.

Comment: Removed oracle tag and applied the oracle-apex tag.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you need, your question as is is confusing.
Do you need basically three filters?? Is it an item or an IG or what, is it a column in an IG,...

Comment: Which version of APEX do you use?

Comment: it's popup lov item , i need three filter tow of this filter selected list an one free text , i think it's complex, i need this because i am work on application to create script ,used in oracle goldengate ,  multi schema and multi table in  two database i need this filter to faster search

Comment: I understand that we don't multi filter functionality for Pop Up LOV in Apex. Although you can try to create 3 PopUp LOV if that works for you.

Comment: Would each filter need to target a specific column?

Comment: yes  , it's  target to specific  column

Answer (score 0):

The way you described it, solution is in 3 separate **Select List** items which are in parent-child relationship. Something like this:

- Continents
- States - whose LoV query should reference *continents*
- Cities - whose Lov query should reference *states*

Never mind whether they are Pop-ups or simple select lists; they'll work just the same.